# PhantomJSでCookieが動作しない

Tags: phantomjs

PhantomJSをDockerで構築し、試しにスクリプトをスクリプトを動かしてみたのですが、Receiveで受け取ったSet-CookieをRequestのヘッダーにセットしてくれないようで、困っています。

Dockerは、下記を使用しています。
https://hub.docker.com/r/cmfatih/phantomjs/

試したスクリプトは、下記です。

```
'use strict';
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
page.open("https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=phantomjs", function(status) {
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('Page Cookie =====================================\n' + JSON.stringify(page.cookies, undefined, 4));
  page.open("https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=phantomjs",function(status) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('Phantom Cookie =====================================\n' + JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies, undefined, 4));
      phantom.exit();
    }, 3000);
  });
}, 3000);
});
```

結果は、こんな感じでHeadersにCookieはセットされていません。

```
Request {
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        }
    ],
    "id": 8,
    "method": "GET",
    "time": "2016-06-02T02:53:19.135Z",
    "url": "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=phantomjs"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースコードを読んで調べたところ、リクエストのヘッダーにCookieの内容を自動的にセットしてくれる機能は無いっぽいです。

自力でやるしか無い！？